# Access model from another route in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this `router.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('analyses', function() {
  this.route('new', { path: 'new'});
  this.route('show', { path: ':analysis_id' });
  this.route('edit', { path: ':analysis_id/edit'});
  this.route('dataFunctions', { path: ':analysis_id/dataFunctions', resetNamespace: true }, function() {
      this.route('new', { path: 'new'});
  });
});

export default Router;
```

and these 2 models

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  dataFunctions: DS.hasMany('dataFunction', {async: true}),
});
```

and

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  analysis: DS.belongsTo('analysis', {async: true})
});
```

The contents of `routes/data-functions/index.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    console.log(this.store.findRecord("analysis", id).get("dataFunctions"));
  }
});
```

The contents of `routes/analyses/index.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
      return this.store.findAll("analysis");
    },

    setupController(controller, model) {
      controller.set("analyses", model);
    }

});
```

The contents of `routes/analyses/show.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('analysis', params.analysis_id);
  },

  setupController(controller, model) {
    controller.set("analysis", model);
  }
});
```

When I navigate to `/analyses/1/dataFunctions` my analysis model is loaded (it is show in ember inspector) but I can’t seem to access it in my `data-functions/index.js` route. How do I go about this? I need the analysis model to extend `findAll` in my data-function adapter to change the url for a rails-api nested resource.

I tried using `this.store.modelFor("analysis").get("id")` but it errors saying get is not a funcion.

I am using Ember 2.0.1 and Ember Data 2.0.0. I am lost here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `this.store.findRecord("analysis", id)` - see http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/the-rest-adapter/

Comment: Can you share code for route where you define `model` function with loaded analysis model? In which place you've tried using `this.store.modelFor...`?

Comment: To access model of a different route you have to explicitly return it, inject it, or it has to be a nested leaf route

Comment: I changed the code around as you guys suggested but still cant find a way to make it work.

Comment: I think you should try answer of @Tyler Iguchi.

Answer (score 1):

It's returning no mode found because you're returning a log statement in the dataFunctions route. Give this a try.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord("analysis", params.analysis_id)
      .then( (analysis) => {
        return analysis.get('dataFuncitons');
      })
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. Since params.analysis_id is nil in this route it gets all analysis, not just the one with id = 1

Comment: Are you passing the model instance when transitioning into the route? You shouldn't be transitioning into the route if you aren't passing in an id in the params.

Comment: I am testing this only accessing the url "/analyses/1/dataFunctions", like if someone bookmarked it. So no transitions are used. Even so, there is a link-to pointing to this route and it passes a analysis model along.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so went through the code there was a few issues. There was a typo in analysis, and the resetNamespace is making things act weird. Also removed some of the redundant path names.

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('analysis', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('show', { path: ':analysis_id' });
    this.route('edit', { path: ':analysis_id/edit'});
    this.route('dataFunctions', { path: ':analysis_id/dataFunctions'}, function() {
        this.route('new');
    });
  });
});
```

Rename the dataFunctions model to data-function to reflect proper conventions, e.g. using singular and dasherizing.

The analysis model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  dataFunctions: DS.hasMany('data-function', {async: true}),
});
```

The data-function model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  analysis: DS.belongsTo('analysis', {async: true})
});
```